# Unable to addForce to my object in Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've done this code but the object isn't moving forward. Can you help me with this?

I'm using unity version 2019.4.3f1

---

```
public class Movements : MonoBehaviour
{
    // A reference to Rigidbody component called "rb"
    public Rigidbody rb;
    public float forwardForce = 10f;
    public float sidewaysForce = 5f;
    
    // Update is called once per frame
    
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb.AddForce(0f , 0f, forwardForce * Time.deltaTime); //Higher the frame rate --> lower the value of force | Time.deltaTime = amount of time since the computer drew last frame
    
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
        {
            Debug.Log("Left");
            rb.AddForce(-sidewaysForce * Time.deltaTime, 0f, 0f, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
        }
        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
        {
            Debug.Log("Right");
            rb.AddForce(sidewaysForce * Time.deltaTime, 0f, 0f, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you need to take account of deltaTime? Physically deltaSpeed = force/mass*deltaTime. Where force/mass = acceleration.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes    You were right, there's no need for that. Thanks! Now it's working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make some changes to your code :)
Here are some suggestions:

- First of all, FixedUpdate() is for Physics stuff (=rb.AddForce) but you should get the input in Update.
- In FixedUpdate, you don't need Time.deltaTime, because it is already called a fixed amount of times per second.
- If you use rb.AddForce it will add more and more Force every time it is called, so your Rigidbody will get faster and faster. If you don't want this, try moving the Rigidbody with changing rb.velocity directly or use rb.MovePosition to move it (I prefer changing rb.velocity directly).

To seperate Inputs and Physics stuff in Update and FixedUpdate you could introduce some private variables at the top like this:

```
private bool leftPressed;
private bool rightPressed;
```

and then you can access these variables in FixedUpdate

Hope I could help :D

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to:

```
public class Movements : MonoBehaviour
    {
        // A reference to Rigidbody component called "rb"
        public Rigidbody rb;
        public float forwardForce = 10f;
        public float sidewaysForce = 5f;
    
        // Update is called once per frame
    
        void FixedUpdate()
        {
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
            {
                Debug.Log("Left");
                rb.AddForce(-sidewaysForce * Time.deltaTime, 0f, 0f, ForceMode.Impulse);
            }
            else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
            {
                Debug.Log("Right");
                rb.AddForce(sidewaysForce * Time.deltaTime, 0f, 0f, ForceMode.Impulse);
            }
        }
    }
```